# macro_rules repeatition does not yield the expected token type

Tags: rust, rust-macros, macro-rules

I am trying to match user-provided lists in a macro, but the repeat-pattern does not match the same branches depending on whether I call the macro on single items directly, or whether I call it from a repeat block.

Input code ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32b6681220cf0cedcd73d9eb3fa33fcb)):

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($a:ident) => { println!("Printing ident"); };
    ($b:literal) => { println!("Printing literal"); };
    ([ $($something:expr),+ $(,)? ]) => {
            println!("Printing repeat");
            $(
                foo!($something);
            )*
    };
    ($catch_all:expr) => { println!("Printing expr"); };
}


fn main() {
    foo!(baz);
    foo!([1, "asd"]);
    foo!([baz]);
}
```

Output:

```
Printing ident
Printing repeat
Printing literal
Printing literal
Printing repeat
Printing expr
```

The first line prints the "ident" line, the last one prints the "expr" line (the other one is just to show that what I want to do works, with literals, at least).

My problem with this behavior is that I also expect `expr` from the user, and now I cannot distinguish raw ident from expr.

To be more specific, I would like to be able to write `foo!(["a literal", some_ident, complex_stuff!()])`, where all three parameters are treated differently.

Comment: BTW: the problem I have here can be avoided simply by using a [TT muncher](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-incremental-tt-munchers.html), and basically matching a concrete ident / literal / expr with a bunch of trailing tt, which we process recursively. This avoids the whole "casting" of the tokens, but forces me to copy-paste some of the code, as well create a recursion where a simple repeat pattern could suffice.

Comment: Unless these are single tokens (in which case you can use `tt` as @cafce25 suggested), TT munching is your only option (except creating a proc macro).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid forcing the type of a token you can match with the type `tt`:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($a:ident) => { println!("Printing ident"); };

    ($b:literal) => { println!("Printing literal"); };

    ([ $($something:tt),+ $(,)? ]) => {
            println!("Printing repeat");
            $(
                foo!($something);
            )*
    };

    ($catch_all:expr) => { println!("Printing expr"); };
}
```

Results in the following with your `main`.

```
Printing ident
Printing repeat
Printing literal
Printing literal
Printing repeat
Printing ident
```

Comment: This only works with single tokens.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, for me [this works for multiple and different tokens as well](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a9ad6ba8721d249fed3690e4c17e76a) just checked nested repeats work too.

Comment: I meant that this only works if each part is composed of a single token.